# Is it possible to make a module iterable in Python?

Tags: python, module, iterable

I am making a module that I want to treat as a static container of objects. These objects are of a class type that I have defined. I want to be able to import this module and then loop over the objects within. Here is some code explaining what I mean:

**example.py**

```
class MyExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4

instanceA = MyExampleClass(1, 2, 3, 4)
instanceB = MyExampleClass(4, 3, 6, 7)
instanceC = MyExampleClass(5, 3, 4, 5)

# something like this
def __iter__():
    return (instanceA, instanceB, instanceC)
```

Then I would like to be able to import this and use it like an enum:

```
import example

for e in example:
   # do stuff with e
```

Is this possible to do in Python? Or will I have to import a list from within the `example` package?

**example.py**

```
objects = (instanceA, instanceB, instanceC)
```

and then

```
import example

for e in example.objects:
    # do stuff with e
```

Comment: The second solution certainly works. Why not use it?

Comment: or if you don't like that version for some reason, the equivalent `from example import objects; for e in objects:`...

Comment: You could probably do it, if you stuff some object into sys.modules that has the proper API for iteration. Not sure if it would need to be derived from `ModuleType.`

Comment: @mdurant I wanted to be able to import just the module and then use it. Guess I need to stop being lazy :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining a root class in your module and replacing the module with an instance of that class. Here is an example:

```
class ModuleClass(object):
    __init__(self):
        self.instanceA = MyExampleClass(1, 2, 3, 4)
        ...

    __iter__(self):
        # Your iterator logic here

# and then in the same module code
sys.modules[__name__] = ModuleClass()
```

So then you can do what you want, because when you import that module, it will actually be an instance of your custom iterable `ModuleClass`:

```
import example

for e in example:
   # do stuff with e
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if I try to import `example` in two separate files; the first file correctly thinks `example` is an instance of `ModuleClass` but the second file still thinks `example` is a module

Comment: My bad; I must have made a mistake. When I created a new project to test this, the errors were gone

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: You can do *almost* anything in python by monkey-patching, but I would consider this an ugly hack and bad style. A cleaner solution would be to just use an `import iterable from module as module` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Although I do not recommend it, you can build your own module by inheriting from `types.ModuleType`. You can then replace the original module with your custom class with `sys.modules[__name__] = NewModule()`

```
import types
import sys

class MyExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4

class MyModule(types.ModuleType):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instanceA = MyExampleClass(1, 2, 3, 4)
        self.instanceB = MyExampleClass(4, 3, 6, 7)
        self.instanceC = MyExampleClass(5, 3, 4, 5)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.instanceA, self.instanceB, self.instanceC])

sys.modules[__name__] = MyModule("example") # Name of the module
```